# What's wrong with 3n+1 program?

Tags: c++

Here is my code for uva 3n+1 problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    while(1){
        long long n, n2, i, iConst, maximum;
        vector<long long> vCycle;
        cin >> n >> n2;
        if(n < n2){
            for(long long i = n; i <= n2; i++){
                long long j = 1;
                iConst = i;
                while(iConst > 1){
                    if(iConst%2 == 0)
                        iConst = iConst / 2;
                    else
                        iConst = (iConst*3)+1;
                    j++;
                }
                vCycle.push_back(j);
            }
        }else{
            for(long long i = n2; i <= n; i++){
                long long j = 1;
                iConst = i;
                while(iConst > 1){
                    if(iConst%2 == 0)
                        iConst = iConst / 2;
                    else
                        iConst = (iConst*3)+1;
                    j++;
                }
                vCycle.push_back(j);
            }
        }
        maximum = *max_element(vCycle.begin(), vCycle.end());
        cout << n << " " << n2 << " " << maximum << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the judge is giving the following error: "Time limit exceed".
Is there anything in my code which is using much CPU?
What's wrong with my program?
*Problem link: [here](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&category=3&problem=36)

Comment: I see `while(1)` and no way of exiting this loop. And eternity slightly exceeds the allowed three seconds limit :)

Comment: That once again demonstrates that *first* reducing the amount of code to the bare minimum and then asking a question is worthwhile.

Comment: Run it on your own system and check results before submitting to the judge

Answer (score 3):

This is not the way, for few numbers it takes a lot of iterations to get the final output where they are already precalculated.

**For Example**

```
for n = 10, 
10
5
16
8
4
2
1

for n = 20,
20
10
5
16
8
4
2
1
for n = 160,
160
80
40
20
10
5
16
8
4
2
1
```

Look at how many numbers are getting repeated, you already calculated the number of steps for 10, when calculating for n = 20, we need not calculate it again when n becomes 10 as we have done it already.

I suggest you to maintain a cache of calculated numbers and check each time if the value is pre-calculated, if yes just give the `number + the existing count`.
else do the math.

This is a Project Euler problem. **Longest Collatz sequence** is what it is called. They need more than code to solve them.

Answer (score 2):

It is timing out because your algorithm is quite inefficient.

Just think of the test case given with the problem description -

> 22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1

When you are generating the sequence for finding the answer for `22`, you can also calculate the answers for every other number in the sequence.

```
int foo( int n )
{
    if ( ans[n] has been calculated )
    {
        return ans[n]
    }

    if ( n is odd )
    {
        ans[n] = foo( 3n + 1 ) + 1
    }
    else
    {
        ans[n] = foo( n / 2 ) + 1
    }
    return ans[n]
}
```

where `ans` is an array of size 10^6.

As far as the task of finding the maximum between any 2 numbers is concerned, you can use a segment tree rather than simply finding the maximum element using a linear search